# Determine if a property value is a blank string

Tags: php

So I have the following `foreach` inside my method as shown below:

```
foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
    $profile->load([
        'azure_picture' => Azure::init()->set_blob_sas_url
        ($profile->get_employee_id()),
        'azure_picture_expiration' =>
            $profile->set_azure_picture_expiration
            (strtotime('+7 days')),
    ]);
    $profile->save();
}
```

So `'azure_picture' => Azure::init()->set_blob_sas_url($profile->get_employee_id()),` will return a `string ''` if the value is empty..

Is there a way that I can determine if `azure_picture` is an empty string, to pass in a empty string in `'azure_picture_expiration' => $profile->set_azure_picture_expiration(strtotime('+7 days')),`..

So instead of passing `strtotime('+7 days')` automatically, I'd like to pass in an empty string if the `azure_picture` is empty, otherwise, use `strtotime('+7 days')`.

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: put the picture inside a variable first so that you only invoke the method once. then follow it up with a simple ternary on the expiration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
    $azure_picture = Azure::init()->set_blob_sas_url
    ($profile->get_employee_id());
    $profile->load([
        'azure_picture' => $azure_picture,
        'azure_picture_expiration' =>
            $profile->set_azure_picture_expiration
            ($azure_picture != '' ? strtotime('+7 days') : ''),
    ]);
    $profile->save();
}
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thanks @netyro, I will try this and follow up.